# Request to re-open "Rosie the Riveter"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm writing to request to re-open the question [Rosie the Riveter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76780/rosie-the-riveter). It was closed as off-topic, but there is an interesting association between the cultural icon of Rosie the Riveter and the expression "We Can Do It!" which emerges in the answers.

Perhaps the question could be retitled *Rosie the Riveter and 'We Can Do It!'* and could be rephrased slightly as follows:

> I have read that Rosie the Riveter is a symbol of the American woman
>   who worked in factories instead of men during the Second World War.
>
> She appears to be associated with the slogan “We Can Do It!” Is this
>   expression still in use nowadays? I mean, do ordinary (American, in
>   particular) people know who is it? Does it preserve its meaning?

The discussion of the expression and its association to Rosie the Riveter might be a worthwhile addition to this site.

Comment: If you think that an edit would help, you can still edit a closed question. It will appear at the top of the "activity"-ordered list of questions, and users can vote to reopen.

Comment: I approved your edit, and I think your edit improves the question, so I voted to reopen. We'll see if 4 more users agree with me

Comment: It's still an interesting cultural question, that is it's not about English language. Or if the question really is about 'We can do it!', well that's still cultural if it's simply 'do people recognize that phrase as being connected with Rosie the Riveter. If it really is about the phrase itself, it's not an idiom, it mean's what it says, and that's worth at most a comment.